# Display data on two tablix from one dataset (Group by) in two different page in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have one dataset group by Loan & Saving. Loan & Saving Report formats are Different. I want to show these two different tablix data in diffrent page in one report. How can i manage it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8rEk.png)

Comment: Please follow prompts like `enter image description here`.

Comment: create both these reports one for loan and one for savings then have a main report with these two as sub reports.